# How to check if there are no parameters provided to a command?

Tags: bash, shell, parameter, shell-script

How do you check if `$*` is empty? In other words, how to check if there were no arguments provided to a command?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

To check if there were no arguments provided to the command, check value of `$#` variable then,

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    >&2 echo "No arguments provided"
    exit 1
fi
```

If you want to use `$*`(**not preferable**) then,

```
if [ "$*" == "" ]; then
    >&2 echo "No arguments provided"
    exit 1
fi
```

Some explanation:

The second approach is not preferable because in positional parameter expansion `*` expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. That means a string is constructed. So there is extra overhead.

On the other hand `#` expands to the number of positional parameters.

Example:

`$ command param1 param2`

Here,

Value of `$#` is 2 and value of `$*` is string "param1 param2" (without quotes), if IFS is unset. Because if IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces

For more details `man bash` and read topic named **Special Parameters**

Comment: Or `if ! (($#)); ...`,
or `if (($# == 0)); ...`,
or `if [ $# -eq 0 ]; ...`, or `! (($#)) && ...`, or `(($#)) || ...`

Comment: `[ $# -eq 0 ]` is the most common form IME. There are edge case where `"$#"` can be empty: if there's a single argument which is empty, or if there are several empty arguments and `$IFS` is empty.

Comment: The `"$*"` expression will also evaluate to `""` if only one `""` parameter was passed. But most of the time you will probably not care about anyway.

Comment: I believe it should be = instead of == ... currently I'm getting an unexpected operator error, and changing to = fixes the problem.

Comment: @Charlotte That means you are not using `bash`. You are using `sh` to execute the script. AFAIK `==` is valid only in `bash`.

Comment: ah, okay. good to know.

Comment: what does `$#` even mean?

Comment: @Michelle "# expands to the number of positional parameters." as stated in answer...

Comment: If you'll indulge me, what is the inverse of this operation? `-neq` didn't work and I'm not doing anything if arguments are missing, so no sense creating that branch unnecessarily.

Comment: Note, if using getops, make sure to run this if statement check before getops is performed.

Answer (score 30):

If you're only interested in bailing if a particular argument is missing, [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#USAGEMESSAGE) is great:

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage-message.sh

: ${1?"Usage: $0 ARGUMENT"}
#  Script exits here if command-line parameter absent,
#+ with following error message.
#    usage-message.sh: 1: Usage: usage-message.sh ARGUMENT
```

Comment: what is the name of this technique using the `?` in the bracket expansion `${}` ? I cannot wrap myn head around the meaning and behaviour of it. I suppose `?` applies to th `1` in `$1` ; but I'm left clueless, I'd gladly dig deeper this technique/syntax.

Comment: aka parameter expansion: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: How about an optional parameter?

Answer (score -3):

this is one of the ways you can know that you havent got any arguments

```
NO_ARGS=0
if [ $# -eq "$NO_ARGS" ]; then
    {do something}
fi
```

Comment: That seems to be a convoluted way of doing what the accepted answer wrote 5 years ago....