# how to pass argument to shell and check if argument is not empty

Tags: shell, parameter

i have this little piece of code lets say `get.sh` that sets the date into a variable like this

```
date=$(date +%b%d%y)
```

now I want to be able to pass custom date parameter to `get.sh` like

```
./get.sh --date=2019-01-01
```

And on the get.sh to be able to make a check if any parameter is sent get the parameter
if not than leave it as it is, so like

```
if ( isset( dateFromCli ) )
date = datefromCLi
else
date=$(date +%b%d%y
```

Comment: Related: [How to check if there are no parameters provided to a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25945/how-to-check-if-there-are-no-parameters-provided-to-a-command)

Comment: Refer to the answer provided by s'kiddie cat. Also, please don't name variables after existing commands, like `date`!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "Special Parameters" on e.g. the Bash man page.  Briefly, you should be able to test **${#}** to determine how many command line parameters were provided, and **${1}**, **${2}**, **${3}**, ... to use the individual parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular problem, this would also work if you are using Bash, shortening your code a little, by allowing you to omit the `if` construct:

`currentDate=${dateFromCLI-+%b%d%y}`

The expression to the right of the equals sign is a special form of parameter expansion, the general form of which is:

`${variableName-"default value"}`

If the variable under the name `variableName` is defined, the whole `${}` construct expands to the value of the variable.

If it is not defined however, then the construct expands to the default value, to the right of the literal hyphen (`-`).
A variable is considered defined if it was assigned to previously and was not unset afterwards. It is even defined if an empty value was assigned to it.

If you have previously set `dateFromCLI` to an empty value, you can use the same style of expansion, but with the `-` substituted by `:-`.
In this case, the default value is also chosen if the named variable is defined, but has a null value (empty string):

`${variableName:-"default value"}`

Reference: [GNU Bash Reference Manual: Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Thanks but I still dont get it :)
This bash thing is driving me crazy

Comment: No wonder, since it _is_ crazy. Whenever you can, avoid the shell. It is unsafe and messy.
What I've provided is a shorthand to get a default value if a variable is not defined.
Think of `${varName-default}` as a special kind of `$varName`, with extra rules due to the dash in the middle. The result of the evaluation is not simply the value of `varName`, a decision is made first. If `varName` is defined, use its value, otherwise, use the default value.