# Taking input in a script and making sure there's only one parameter

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm currently working on an assignment where I have a script that is basically just getting to learn using grep with different regex's.

I have the script written except for the first part where I am asked to take a file as input and then the script runs based on that file.

I have the prompt for input, the read command after, the grep commands. Everything works fine, I just need to implement an if statement I believe that would run the script if it only has 1 parameter given. 
- The assignment says that the script should only run if 1 and only 1 parameter is given otherwise it should display an error message.

Thanks,

Comment: Well, here's how to [How to check if there are no parameters provided to a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25945/how-to-check-if-there-are-no-parameters-provided-to-a-command) - see if you can modify it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a script `$#` will expand to the number of positional parameters.  We can use that to check if the correct number of options have been passed, and exit right away if not:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    printf 'ERROR! You must provide one and only one argument!\n' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Places you can read about this:

[2.5.1 Positional Parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_01)

[The if Conditional Construct](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07)

[2.7.2 Redirecting Output](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_02)